# Team foundation server, Update test cases using api

Tags: c#, tfs

So we are currently updating Test cases using the TFS api.  The problem is that when we try to update more than x amount of Test cases per run only a portion of those test cases are updated.  I was hoping someone can tell me if TFS has a setting for the amount of Test Cases / work items that can be updated per session.

If it does what should I look for and how will it affect the rest of my team?

To give more insight into this, we try to update +- 1600 Test cases after our integration tests have ran.  only a portion of these tests will update, if we run less that 800 all the corresponding Test Cases are updated correctly.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Could it just be timing out?

Comment: I thought that as well, but found that the application throws a Out of memory exception

Comment: Please share more information of the error message.

Comment: And check your code to see whether there is memory leaks. Check this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx to try to catch the exception.

Comment: so I found the culprit in this, we were compiling the application in X86 witch means a collection has a maximum of 2gb allocated in memory.  The list we have far exceeds this amount, when we compiled in X64 everything is working as expected.  Thanks @Cece-MSFT for the idea, try catch actually pointed me in to correct direction.